# For each country find product's category which were the most popular - subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

The tables are given:

```
1) Categories: id, name
2) Countries: id, name
3) Producers: id, name, country_id
4) Products: id, name, price, category_id, producer_id
5) Customers: id, name, surname, age, country_id
6) Customer_orders: id, customer_id, product_id, quantity, discount, order_date
```

I want to find the most popular product's category for each country (most popular products category - products were produced by producers from specified country)

My current apporach:

```
select countries.name, categories.name, sum(cs.quantity) from countries
join producers on producers.country_id = countries.id
join products on products.producer_id = producers.id
join categories on categories.id = products.category_id
join customerorders as cs on cs.product_id = products.id
group by countries.name
```

That's not actually the good solution. Not sure how to do it, I suppose I should group all prodcts by country, and then for each country count the number of products for each product's category (products produced by producers from specified country) and finally find the category with most products bought.

Comment: That query is invalid. Which MySQL version are you using? (You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.)

Comment: This is how you should handle [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) in MySQL @jarlh is right *"You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions."*  But there are cases where `SELECT * FROM t GROUP BY id` can infact be valid SQL because of [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) (SQL 1999+ optional feature)

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your `group by` and then use window functions:

```
select c.*
from (select co.name as country_name, c.name as category_name, sum(co.quantity) as total_qty,
             row_number() over (partition by co.name order by sum(co.quantity) desc) as seqnum
      from countries co join
           producers pr
           on pr.country_id = co.id join
           products p
           on p.producer_id = pr.id join
           categories c
           on c.id = p.category_id join
           customerorders co
           on co.product_id = p.id
      group by co.name, c.name
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

This should work in MySQL 8+.  It is possible to express this in earlier versions but a bit of a pain.

Comment: @Ares02 . . . That is a rather vague comment.